# Weather API tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I have a service which provide data from the weather data:

```
getCurrentWeatherData(location: Location, target?: string) {
    return this.http.get<CurrentWeatherAPI>(
        `${this.apiUrl}current?${
            target === 'inputBtn' || target === 'enter'
                ? '&city=' + location.city
                : '&lat=' + location.latitude + '&lon=' + location.longitude
        }&key=${this.apiKey}&lang=pl`
    );
}
```

And tests for that:

```
describe('GetWeatherDataService', () => {
    let httpController: HttpTestingController;
    let service: GetWeatherData;
    const location = {
        city: 'name',
        latitude: 67,
        longitude: 10,
    };

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [GetWeatherData, HttpClient],
        }).compileComponents();

        service = TestBed.inject(GetWeatherData);
        httpController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    });

    it('service should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('#getCurrentWeatherData should use GET to retrieve data', () => {
        service.getCurrentWeatherData(location, 'enter').subscribe();

        const testRequest = httpController.expectOne(
            'https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?&city=Name&key=1929292&lang=eu'
        );
        expect(testRequest.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    });
});
```

My problem is that I want to check that the name of the city from the variable location is equal to real data getting from the API. I don't know how to get json from the API using testing module.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use real API in unitTests. Instead of this mock HttpClient.

https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#testing-http-services